# Analysis of PCA

Tags: r, pca

I'm using the `rela` package to check whether I can use PCA in my data.

```
paf.neur2 <- paf(neur2)
summary(paf.neur2)
# [1] "Your dataset is not a numeric object."
```

I want to see the KMO (The Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin measure of sampling adequacy test). How to do that?

Output of str(neur2)

```
  'data.frame': 1457 obs. of  66 variables:
   $ userid : int  200 387 458 649 931 991 1044 1075 1347 1360 ...
   $ funct  : num  3.73 3.79 3.54 3.04 3.81 ...
   $ pronoun: num  2.26 2.55 2.49 1.98 2.71 ...
      .
      .
      . 
   $ time   : num  1.68 1.87 1.51 1.03 1.74 ...
   $ work   : num  0.7419 0.2311 -0.1985 -1.6094 -0.0619 ...
   $ achieve: num  0.174 0.2469 0.1823 -0.478 -0.0513 ...
   $ leisure: num  0.2852 0.0296 0.0583 -0.3567 -0.0408 ...
   $ home   : num  -0.844 -0.58 -0.844 -2.207 -1.079 ...
      .
```

Variables are all numeric.

Comment: Please post the output of `str(neur2)`.

Comment: Posted. The output is too long, but all the variables are numeric.

Comment: After you are done with the PCA, I would like to suggest that you compare the percentage of variation extracted by each of your principal components to  broken stick model results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `?paf`, `object` is a *numeric dataset (usually a coerced matrix from a prior data frame)*

So you need to turn your data.frame `neur2` into a matrix: `as.matrix(neur2)`.

Here is a reproduction of your problem using the `Seatbelts` dataset:

```
library(rela)

Belts <- Seatbelts[,1:7]
class(Belts)
# [1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"

Belts <- as.data.frame(Belts)
# [1] "data.frame"

paf.belt <- paf(Belts)
[1] "Your dataset is not a numeric object."

Belts <- as.matrix(Belts)
class(Belts)
# [1] "matrix"

paf.belt <- paf(Belts)  # Works
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options which can do it for you:

```
kmo_DIY <- function(df){ 
csq = cor(df)^2 
csumsq = (sum(csq)-dim(csq)[1])/2 
library(corpcor) 
pcsq = cor2pcor(cor(df))^2 
pcsumsq = (sum(pcsq)-dim(pcsq)[1])/2 
kmo = csumsq/(csumsq+pcsumsq) 
return(kmo) 
}
```

or

the function KMO() from the psych package.